# Parse string to data and retrieve hours

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am try to convert this string "`2014-07-23 09:00:00"` into something like this `"9 PM"`. My code is:

```
 public void printTime() {
        String data = "2014-07-23 09:00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
        SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ha",Locale.UK);
        Log.v(LOG, "Time is" + f2.format(f1.format(data)));
    }
```

But have this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
    at launcher.alpentouch.com.myapplication.MainActivity.printTime(MainActivity.java:30)
    at launcher.alpentouch.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your code is in error. You can't nest format like that. Rather you would parse the data, then format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "2014-07-23 09:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + " PM") ;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

9 PM

Comment: Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. For example if your time will be 19:00:00, this codel will return "19 PM"

Answer (score 2):

Don't fear to use the new Java 8 Time API so you don't run into problems like accidentally calling `SimpleDateFormat.format(Object)`.

```
String data = "2014-07-23 09:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter destinationFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h a");
String output = LocalDateTime.parse(data, sourceFormatter).format(destinationFormatter);
```

Comment: nice! didnt know this

Comment: @Judge Yes, these java.time classes supplant the poorly-designed troublesome legacy date-time classes. Built into Java 8 and later. For Android see the ThreeTenABP and ThreeTen-Backport projects. Well worth the bother adding this library to your app. Search Stack Overflow for “java.time” for many discussions and examples. I also suggest learning about the ISO 8601 standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
f2.format(f1.format(data))
```

makes no sense as you are trying to use a DateFormat to format a *String*. These objects *parse* Strings to Dates and *format* Dates to Strings. So instead you would use your DateFormat object to parse the String to a Date, and then format the result back to a String:

```
f2.format(f1.parse(data))
```

When running into such errors, it's best to not try to make nested calls on one line since this will make it harder for you to find your error. So better:

```
Date d = f1.parse(data);
String dateString = f2.format(d);
```

... at least until you fix the error. This way you'll know which part of your nested code is in error since the JVM will point directly to the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

reading the date string you have, a think this is the ISO pattern (or a simplified form of it).
Using this code you will get what you want:

```
public void printTime(){
    // i think ISO allow a space between date and time, but our interpreter not
  String data = "2014-07-23 13:00:00";
  data = data.replace(' ', 'T'); // <<<---  Caution here!

  SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("h a", Locale.UK);
  Calendar cad = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(data);

  System.out.printf("Your format: %s \n", f1.format( cad.getTime() ) );
}
```

The `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` can parse this ISO pattern *(with attention to the **T** between date and time)*, and with the calendar *(and Date, calling `.getTime()` from `Calendar`)* you can format to what you want.

But if you need a solution that receive a diferente type of date formatting you will need to be more specific regarding to this format.

One of the reasons to be using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` here is that this parser can accept *"diferent forms"* of the ISO format. All these will be valid strings for that parser:
- `"2014-07-23"`
- `"2014-07-23T13:00:00"`
- `"2014-07-23T13:00:00.100Z"`

Only with `SimpleDateFormat` you cannot parse the strings above, because `SimpleDateFormat` doesnt have a syntax flexible enough to declarer how to interpreter *"different forms"* of an input date string. So you end up with a solution that do checks on input string to define what is your `SimpleDateFormat` instance you need to use *(maybe using RegExp to find the patterns on input string)*.